# Ввод данных в браузере для компилятора

Tags: java, spring, rest

Мне нужно создать простое Rest-приложение, в котором у меня есть бд пользователей. Проект пишется на Spring. Есть метод по добавлению нового пользователя. Столкнулся с проблемой, что не знаю, как создать текстовое поле в браузере, в котором пользователь будет вводить свои данные. Знаю только основы JavaScript, придется пользоваться `prompt`? Как оттуда забрать данные в компилятор?

Answer (score 1):

Вы бы код привели.

Если абстрактно, то внутри метода создавайте ModelAndView.

Кладите в него jsp страницу и объек для данных (создайте класс описывающий сущность данных, которое надо передавать).

model.setView(jsp страница)

model.addObject(имя объекта, объект)

На стринце jsp с помощью spring:form можете создать форму с нужными полями, спринг за вас  создаст нужный вам объект и передаст его.

Чтобы получить его, в методе к атрибуту объекта добавьте аннотацию @ModelAttribut